# MySQL INSERT IGNORE or ON DUPLICATE KEY DO_NOTHING

Tags: mysql

already searched for such topics and found 2 different solutions but noone works.

My table has structure | ID (auto_increment primary_key) | UID (int) | FAV_ID (int) |

I need to insert new record to this FAV_TABLE if UID and FAV_ID (both) already exist.

Example of my query:

```
INSERT INTO FAV_TABLE (uid, fav_id) VALUES ($u_id,$s_id) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  uid = uid
```

or this one

```
INSERT IGNORE FAV_TABLE (uid, fav_id) VALUES ($u_id,$s_id);
```

As mysql manuals says this query doesn't add record only if PRIMARY_KEY is the same. 
And I need query not to add record if pair uid+fav_id is unique.
Any solutions? Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a `UNIQUE KEY` on those columns:

```
ALTER TABLE FAV_TABLE ADD UNIQUE KEY(uid, fav_id);
```

Answer (score 2):

`INSERT IGNORE` or `ON DUPLICATE KEY` works only when a unique key is duplicated.

You need to add a `UNIQUE` index on both fields `uid` and `fav_id`.
That way, when you insert a duplicate pair, it will be ignored.